# Rails 3, mysql/mysql2 misinterpreting some retrieved strings as ASCII-8BIT

Tags: mysql, encoding, ruby-on-rails-3, character-encoding, mysql2

This problem began as the commonly-seen “incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8” problem, but that is ***not*** what I'm asking. Rather, I discovered that this problem was happening because certain fields of my database are being tagged as ASCII-8BIT when they're retrieved, while most are correctly shown as UTF-8.

For example, in a table with columns `country` and `nationality`, where both columns in row 16 have identical values (copied-and-pasted), I get

```
irb(main):003:0> c = Country.find(16)
irb(main):004:0> puts "#{c.name}, #{c.name.encoding}, #{c.name.bytes.to_a}"
�land Islands, UTF-8, [195, 133, 108, 97, 110, 100, 32, 73, 115, 108, 97, 110, 100, 115]
irb(main):005:0> puts "#{c.nationality}, #{c.nationality.encoding}, #{c.nationality.bytes.to_a}"
�land Islands, ASCII-8BIT, [195, 133, 108, 97, 110, 100, 32, 73, 115, 108, 97, 110, 100, 115]
```

Likewise, a simple `puts name` gives `�land Islands` while for `nationality` it gives `"\xC3\x85land Islands"` -- same bytes, different presentation.

The encoding for a given column appears to be constant regardless of whether the string has non-ascii characters, so it is not simply a problem with the string. That is, *all* the values in `nationality` are interpreted as ascii and *all* those in `name` as UTF-8.

The problem is not limited to a single table, and I have not found any pattern to which columns are mis-recognized.

Here are the settings and environment:

- Rails 3.0.0 on Windows 7 64-bit
- Database adapter: mysql2 and mysql both show same behavior
- Database.yml includes `encoding: utf8`
- application.rb includes `config.encoding = "utf-8"`
- MySQL database, table, and both columns are defined as utf8
- Both columns in MySQL are varchar, 255, allow null
- I can reproduce the problem with a fresh installation of Rails and nothing except the Country model defined, to access the database. I have not yet tried with a fresh, one-line database.

Anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same problem here! [mysql2 gem, Rails 3.0.3 and "incompatible character encodings" errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920351/mysql2-gem-rails-3-0-3-and-incompatible-character-encodings-errors)

Comment: Sounds good. It has been so long that I no longer remember how I solved this myself!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, use ruby-mysql gem instead mysql or mysql2 gems.

Answer (score -1):

I think I'm living a similar problem.

When I retrivied datas from MySQL DB rails convert a string to float:

Columns "Complemento" and "estado" are string in DB although action "show" says 
Complemento: 0.0 -> at DB is "apto 191"

Escola was successfully created.

Nome: Silva Braga

Endereco: Rua Dr Arnaldo

Numero: 99

Complemento: 0.0 -> DB is "apto 191"

Cidade: São Paulo

Estado: 0.0 -> DB is "MG"

Edit | Back

Comment: please put this under comment

Comment: This is likely a different issue since it involves a change from string to float. I suggest you open a new question for it and give the sort of details that will help people help you.